# System.InvalidOperationException: Could not read Sitecore configuration

Tags: app-config, sitecore, sitecore6

I have installed sitecore, created website in iis(6.1) and then mapped properly to the physical folder. When i add a test file (default.aspx) and browse, file load up. But when i try to open content editor (eg: http://localhost:XXXX/sitecore), I see the error 
**System.InvalidOperationException: Could not read Sitecore configuration**

I'm guessing that, a small configuration is missing which is taking me through long go.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install sitecore? Did you use the installer or the zip?  And if you used the zip file installation method did you follow the installation manual for settings permissions and such?

Comment: Yes Patrick, IT was permission issue. Thanks :)

Comment: This question is resolved, but I just want to comment you can also get the "Could not read Sitecore configuration" error if your web.config is accidentally copied over during a publish from Visual Studio.

Comment: This was happen in mycase , after giving proper permission I was getting this error, later check that my Web.config file was completely changed through nuget package , Thanks  @ADH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Patrick says, It was just an permission set to the proj folder. I have unchecked **Read Only** property of the folder.